# how to connect oracle in excel in windows 7 64 bit

Tags: sql, excel, oracle, odbc

I am trying to connect to Oracle Database with MS Excel 2007 in windows 7 64-bit.
The oracle database being present in my manager laptop, and I have database name,username,password and IP address. When I am trying to connect I get below image error.
Please help me in these with simple steps!!
[image]

Comment: The error message indicates that the Oracle client is not installed on the local machine. Is the database on the same machine or a different one?

Comment: its on a different pc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message indicates that the Oracle client is not installed on the local machine. You say the database is on a different machine (server). ODBC cannot access remote software: you need to install the Oracle client software on the PC where you want to use Excel.

The Oracle Instant Client should have everything you need. It's a lightweight install designed for just this scenario. [Download it from OTN here.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html)

Comment: there are many "Instant Client Package" options which one shall i choose?

Comment: fnord. Choose the one which matches the OS of your client machine. If you're using Excel that narrows it down to one of the Windows installs - 32bit or 64bit depending on what you're using.

Comment: Apc it is still not working please find the easiest way

Comment: ORA-12504:TNS:listener was not given the SERVICE_NAME in CONNECT_DATA EXCEL

Comment: There is some problem with the configuration. Perhaps your local TNSNAMES.ORA is mis-configured for the server's LISTENER.ORA file (we need to put the correct database service name in the local file). But there are other causes. This is really not the sort of thing which can be diagnosed remotely. Don't you have a DBA resource who can help you with this?

Comment: APC Tell me please its urgent "CLIENT" should have oracle database including oracle instant client for eg: you have database and am a client and i want  to use ur database so for me its necessary to install oracle database including oracle instant client  or not?

Comment: The client needs to have the software which allows it to connect to the database. That is the software in the Oracle Instant Client download. The client also needs to be configured to connect to the remote database. Installing database server software on the client machine isn't going to help you achieve any of that.

Comment: As for urgency, I'm afraid that is not my bailiwick. It's down to your organisation to provide you with the expert help you need to complete your task.

Comment: APK thank you! its very clear way to achieve the target.

Comment: Unable to connect SQLState=08004 [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified when i am adding two service names in one tnsnames.ora